# Get all JS variables that begin with a certain string

Tags: javascript, optimization, refactoring, global-variables

I'm writing a plugin for a website that I have no control over except my ability to add JS code to it (in fact it's a set of html docs generated by an obsolete wysiwyg html editor).

For my purposes, I need to get all variables that are named in a certain way. The name always begins with `zzz` and ends with a number, from `zzz1` to `zzz999999`. Right now I'm doing the following:

```
for (var i=1; i<999999; i++) {
    if (typeof window['zzz'+i] !== 'undefined') { 
       ArrayOfAllFoundVariables.push( window['zzz'+i] )
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to detect these variables other than iterating through a million of undefineds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can iterate through all top level variables (properties of `window`), and then test if their name match some regex pattern. Collect the matching variables as before.

```
var pattern = /^zzz[0-9]+/;
for (var varName in window) {
    if (pattern.test(varName)) {
        ArrayOfAllFoundVariables.push(window[varName]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mikke beat me to it :)

```
for (element in window) {
  if (element.substring(0,3) == 'zzz') {
    ArrayOfAllFoundVariables.push(window[element]);
  }
```

}

but I missed out the number part :) ... well done Mikke ...